# При щелчке на меню запоминать путь

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть меню. Не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы при клике по нему сохранялся его путь. Например, как в Яндекс.Диске, когда пользователь выбирает «скопировать» или «вставить». Вот мой пример кода:

```css
img { 
  border: none; 
}
p {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
  
/* Стили для дерева каталогов */
ol.tree {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  width: 300px;
}
li { 
  position: relative; 
  margin-left: -15px;
  list-style: none;
}
li.file {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
}
li.file a {
  background: url(img/document.png) 0 2px no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
li.file a:hover {
  color: #aff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
li.toggle {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/ichL75/folder_horizontal.png) 15px 1px no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 37px;
}
li input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  top: 0;
}
li input + ol {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/kn6PZk/toggle_small_expand.png) 5px -3px no-repeat;
  margin: -0.938em 0 0 -44px; /* 15px */
  height: 1em;
}
li input + ol > li { 
  display: none; 
  margin-left: -14px !important; 
  padding-left: 1px; 
}
li input:checked + ol {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/geQJuk/toggle_small_1.png) 5px 2px no-repeat;
  margin: -1.25em 0 0 -44px; /* 20px */
  padding: 1.563em 0 0 80px;
  height: auto;
}
li input:checked + ol > li { display: block; margin: 0 0 0.125em;  /* 2px */}
li input:checked + ol > li:last-child { margin: 0 0 0.063em; /* 1px */ }
```

```html
<ol class="tree">
  <li class="toggle">
    fdgdfg
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    777
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
      <li class="toggle">
        111
        <input type="checkbox">
        <ol class="tree">
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    123
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
      <li class="toggle">
        123
        <input type="checkbox">
        <ol class="tree">
          <li class="toggle">
            2
            <input type="checkbox">
            <ol class="tree">
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    ж
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    clients
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
      <li class="toggle">
        Загрузки
        <input type="checkbox">
        <ol class="tree">
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="toggle">
        img
        <input type="checkbox">
        <ol class="tree">
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    tree
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    555
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    img
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
      <li class="toggle">
        home
        <input type="checkbox">
        <ol class="tree">
          <li class="toggle">
            z1
            <input type="checkbox">
            <ol class="tree">
              <li class="toggle">
                .purple
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                .cache
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                .thunderbird
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                .git
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                .gimp-2.8
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                Музыка
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                .icons
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                .swt
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                .ssr
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                .netbeans
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                .wine
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                .themes
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                .Skype
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                Документы
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                Изображения
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                Шаблоны
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="toggle">
                Рабочий стол
                <input type="checkbox">
                <ol class="tree">
                </ol>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    js
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    css
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    ccc
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
      <li class="toggle">
        vvvv
        <input type="checkbox">
        <ol class="tree">
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    images
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике на папку путь к этой папке сохранялся в отдельную переменную.

Comment: В каком формате должен путь сохраняться? Уровень1 - уровень2 - уровень3?

Comment: @Cheg 777/123 но выбираться всего один если клик по новой папке то новый путь

Comment: Куда сохраняться? В кеш, чтоб при перезагрузке страницы папка оставалась открытой? Уточните вопрос

Comment: @larrymacbarry при перезагрузке страницы не нужно что бы сохранялась, при перезагрузке все обновляется, то есть  сделал клик по папке то место до куда открыто меню сохраняется путь

Comment: и куда сохраняется путь? В переменную-буфер js или как запрос в адресной строке или ещё куда?

Comment: @larrymacbarry в переменную буфер js , что бы потом я его мог передать в php для обработки

Comment: в каком виде вы хотели бы путь?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63226/discussion-between-vadim-and-larrymacbarry).

Comment: @larrymacbarry я хочу получить его в виде 777/121
названия папок через /

Comment: В чате вопрос вам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("b#path").click(function(){
         var path = $( "input:checked:last" ).val();
            alert(path);
          });
 });
```

```css
img { 
  border: none; 
}
p {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
button.noShow {
    display: none;
} 
/* Стили для дерева каталогов */
ol.tree {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  width: 300px;
}
li { 
  position: relative; 
  margin-left: -15px;
  list-style: none;
}
li.file {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
}
li.file a {
  background: url(img/document.png) 0 2px no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
li.file a:hover {
  color: #aff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
li.toggle {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/ichL75/folder_horizontal.png) 15px 1px no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 37px;
}
li input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  top: 0;
}
li input + ol {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/kn6PZk/toggle_small_expand.png) 5px -3px no-repeat;
  margin: -0.938em 0 0 -44px; /* 15px */
  height: 1em;
}
li input + ol > li { 
  display: none; 
  margin-left: -14px !important; 
  padding-left: 1px; 
}
li input:checked + ol {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/geQJuk/toggle_small_1.png) 5px 2px no-repeat;
  margin: -1.25em 0 0 -44px; /* 20px */
  padding: 1.563em 0 0 80px;
  height: auto;
}
li input:checked + ol > li { display: block; margin: 0 0 0.125em;  /* 2px */}
li input:checked + ol > li:last-child { margin: 0 0 0.063em; /* 1px */ }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="tree"><li class="toggle" value="./123"><b id="path" value="./123">123</b><input value="./123" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"><li class="toggle" value="./123/000"><b id="path" value="./123/000">000</b><input value="./123/000" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./123/000">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./123/444"><b id="path" value="./123/444">444</b><input value="./123/444" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./123/444">tt</button></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./123">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./ds"><b id="path" value="./ds">ds</b><input value="./ds" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"><li class="toggle" value="./ds/000"><b id="path" value="./ds/000">000</b><input value="./ds/000" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./ds/000">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./ds/444"><b id="path" value="./ds/444">444</b><input value="./ds/444" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./ds/444">tt</button></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./ds">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./roman"><b id="path" value="./roman">roman</b><input value="./roman" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./roman">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./5151"><b id="path" value="./5151">5151</b><input value="./5151" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"><li class="toggle" value="./5151/000"><b id="path" value="./5151/000">000</b><input value="./5151/000" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./5151/000">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./5151/444"><b id="path" value="./5151/444">444</b><input value="./5151/444" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./5151/444">tt</button></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./5151">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./img"><b id="path" value="./img">img</b><input value="./img" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./img">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./007"><b id="path" value="./007">007</b><input value="./007" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"><li class="toggle" value="./007/000"><b id="path" value="./007/000">000</b><input value="./007/000" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./007/000">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./007/444"><b id="path" value="./007/444">444</b><input value="./007/444" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./007/444">tt</button></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./007">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./js"><b id="path" value="./js">js</b><input value="./js" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./js">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./css"><b id="path" value="./css">css</b><input value="./css" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./css">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./images"><b id="path" value="./images">images</b><input value="./images" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./images">tt</button><li class="toggle" value="./dfgjmdf"><b id="path" value="./dfgjmdf">dfgjmdf</b><input value="./dfgjmdf" type="checkbox"><ol class="tree"></ol></li><button class="noShow" type="submit" value="./dfgjmdf">tt</button></ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то можно сделать вот так (обернул названия папок в `span`, чтоб было на что обработчик вешать):

```js
var path = '';
$('span').on('click', function() {
  var arr = [];
  $(this).parents('li').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).find('span').first().text());
  });
  path = arr.reverse().join('/');
  console.log(path);
});
```

```css
img {
  border: none;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}


/* Стили для дерева каталогов */

ol.tree {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  width: 300px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -15px;
  list-style: none;
}

li.file {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
}

li.file a {
  background: url(img/document.png) 0 2px no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

li.file a:hover {
  color: #aff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

li.toggle {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/ichL75/folder_horizontal.png) 15px 1px no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 37px;
}

li input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  top: 0;
}

li input+ol {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/kn6PZk/toggle_small_expand.png) 5px -3px no-repeat;
  margin: -0.938em 0 0 -44px;
  /* 15px */
  height: 1em;
}

li input+ol>li {
  display: none;
  margin-left: -14px !important;
  padding-left: 1px;
}

li input:checked+ol {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/geQJuk/toggle_small_1.png) 5px 2px no-repeat;
  margin: -1.25em 0 0 -44px;
  /* 20px */
  padding: 1.563em 0 0 80px;
  height: auto;
}

li input:checked+ol>li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0.125em;
  /* 2px */
}

li input:checked+ol>li:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 0.063em;
  /* 1px */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="tree">
  <li class="toggle">
    <span>fdgdfg</span>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    <span>777</span>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
      <li class="toggle">
        <span>111</span>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <ol class="tree">
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="toggle">
        <span>222</span>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <ol class="tree">
          <li class="toggle">
            <span>2</span>
            <input type="checkbox">
            <ol class="tree">
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle">
    <span>123</span>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ol class="tree">
      <li class="toggle">
        <span>123</span>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <ol class="tree">
          <li class="toggle">
            <span>2</span>
            <input type="checkbox">
            <ol class="tree">
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: я решил проблему еще тогда я не много php изменил,а в jquery поиск по открывшимся чекбоксам сделал , но спасибо за помощь